# Regular Expression to Match any Number of Characters in the Middle of a Defined String

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regular expression to match a particular pattern.

If a sample test string is as follows:

```
/wp-content/themes/sometheme/style.css
```

The regular expression should:

1. MATCH `/wp-content/themes/` exactly, from the beginning, and should also match `/style.css` exactly, from the end.
2. NOT MATCH, when the remainder (between the beginning and end strings in item 1) is `rwsarbor`
3. MATCH, when the remainder is anything BUT `mythemename`
4. For the dynamic part in the middle, it should match any number of characters, and any character type (not just a-z, 0-9, etc)

For example, it should not match:

```
/wp-content/themes/mythemename/style.css
```

It should match

```
/wp-content/themes/jfdskjh-ekhb234_sf/style.css
/wp-content/themes/another_theme/style.css
/wp-content/themes/any_other-theme/style.css
/wp-content/themes/!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"?</style.css
```

This one is a little out of my league in terms of complexity, so I am looking to the community for assistance.

Comment: Give an example of a string NOT being matched (regarding that `rwsarbor` thing and I'll integrate that in my answer too.

Comment: Language/environment where the regex is used in would be fine, since they differ.

Comment: Clarifications:

@Dr.Kameleon - Sorry that was a mistake in the original question (and I have now updated the post accordingly) - the string it should not match should have been:

    /wp-content/themes/rwsarbor/style.css

Comment: @user unknown - this is being used in an nginx/php environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
^/wp-content/themes/(?!mythemename).*/style.css$
```

**Demo :** http://regexr.com?30ote

---

***Hint :** Using [Negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).*

Comment: this solution fits the need perfectly (after swapping out `mythemename` with `rwsarbor`). Thanks for taking the time to include a demo, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just make two regex out of it, one to match, and one to not match (here doing it with grep):

```
 echo /wp-content/themes/sametheme/style.css | egrep "^/wp-content/themes/.*/style.css$" | egrep -v "(simetheme|sametheme)"
```

Instead of rwsarbor and mytheme I choosed something better testable.

A shorter demo would have been fine, btw: /start/middle/end

Answer (score 0):

Vim regex:

```
^\/wp-content\/themes\/\(rwsarbor\|mythemename\)\@!.\{-}\/style\.css$
```

Important bits:

```
\(__\|__\) - match one or the other pattern
\@! - match if the preceeding atom didn't match
.\{-\} - Like .* but non-greedy, otherwise style.css would get sucked up here
```

Syntax and modifiers are dependent on the specific regex engine you're going to use.